# Unable to catch PHPException with socket_connect within a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to ignore a PHP error via a try catch block but it doesn't seem to be working? I'm using it inside of of my controllers in Laravel.

```php
try {
    if (!self::isEmulatorOnline()) {
        return;
    }

    $MUSdata = $command . chr(1) . $data;
    $socket = \socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));

    $connect_timeval = array(
        "sec"=>0,
        "usec" => 100
    );

    \socket_set_option(
        $socket,
        SOL_SOCKET,
        SO_SNDTIMEO,
        $connect_timeval
    );

    \socket_connect($socket, Config::get('frontend.client_host_ip'), Config::get('frontend.mus_host_port'));
    \socket_send($socket, $MUSdata, strlen($MUSdata), MSG_DONTROUTE);     
    \socket_close($socket);
    }
catch(\PHPException $exception) {}
```

As you can see I am trying to silent the error exception, I know it is advised not to but its via an ajax request where I handle if the client IP and port can't be accessed using a different method.

Does anyone know why its returning the error exception even when making it silent out using try catch?

The error I am getting is

```
1/1) ErrorException
socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

On this line:

```
 \socket_connect($socket, Config::get('frontend.client_host_ip'), Config::get('frontend.mus_host_port'));
```

Comment: `catch(\Exception $ex){ ... }` can be used to catch any of Laravel's exceptions, or you can add multiple `catch()` blocks if you need specific actions for specific exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to catch the wrong exception. `socket_connect()` throws an `ErrorException` and not an `PHPException`. You can also specify just the `Exception` class to catch **all** [unhandled exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

You can also add multiple catch blocks if you want to catch multiple exception classes to handle them differently.

Example:

```
try {
    //
} catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    // here you go.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought PHPException was the parent of all other exceptions but clearly I was wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can catch error like this.
Try logging this

```
try {
 //
} catch (\Exception $e) {
 // catch error message
 Log::info($e->getMessage());

// get http error code
 Log::info($e->getCode());
}
```